# If/Then statement issue

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a if/then statement that will open a form based on a pats action number. The issue is , I recently ran into a problem where some people won't have a pats action number. How do I frame this code so that the form will open based on the position number if there is no pats action number.

```
If Me.txtPATS <> "" Then
    If Me.Action_Type <> "Job Opening" Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "sfrmPAR", , , "PATS_ActionID=" & Me.PATS_ActionID,    acFormEdit
    End If
    If Me.Action_Type = "Job Opening" Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "sfrmPARVacancy", , , "PATS_ActionID=" & Me.PATS_ActionID, acFormEdit
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenForm "sfrmPAR", , , "[Position_ #]='" & Me.txtPos & "'", acFormEdit
    End If
    If txt.PATS = Null Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "sfrmPARVacancy", , , Action_Type = " & Me.Action_Type, acFormEdit"
    End If
End If
```

Comment: You would find it much easier to understand what's happening if you indent your code correctly, which I have now done for you

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
If Nz(Me!txtPATS.Value) <> "" Then
    If Me.Action_Type <> "Job Opening" Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "sfrmPAR", , , "PATS_ActionID=" & Me.PATS_ActionID, acFormEdit
    End If
    If Me.Action_Type = "Job Opening" Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "sfrmPARVacancy", , , "PATS_ActionID=" & Me.PATS_ActionID, acFormEdit
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenForm "sfrmPAR", , , "[Position_ #]='" & Me.txtPos & "'", acFormEdit
    End If
    If IsNull(txt.PATS) Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "sfrmPARVacancy", , , Action_Type = " & Me.Action_Type, acFormEdit"
    End If
End If
```